# simple random sampling without replacement proof

Tags: statistics, sampling

For simple random sampling without replacement, starting
with the expectation of $\sum_1^n(y_i-\bar Y)^2$, show that $V(\bar y)= 
(1 − f )S^2/n$

this looks very hard i tried to simplify the right side but it doesnt give me anything may someone guide me through this please? Am i missing some important concepts?

Comment: You need to add some more details: what is Y? What is f?

Comment: oh sorry Y is the population and yi is sample and f is n/N